# How to escape to binary data in python

Tags: python

I'm playing with pythonchallenge level8

I try to get the un and pw directly from the url

```
text = urllib.urlopen('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/integrity.html').read()
un_pat = re.compile('un: \'(.+)\'')
compress_un = un_pat.findall(text)[0]
```

But actually un should be like this

```
un = 'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
```

Is there any simple way (except write a loop myself) to convert compress_un to un? Does python offer some library to do this? Thanks

Comment: What does `compress_un` contain?

Comment: `'BZh91AY&SYA\\xaf\\x82\\r\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x80\\x02\\xc0\\x02\\x00 \\x00!\\x9ah3M\\x07<]\\xc9\\x14\\xe1BA\\x06\\xbe\\x084'`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> compress_un
'BZh91AY&SYA\\xaf\\x82\\r\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x80\\x02\\xc0\\x02\\x00 \\x00!\\x9ah3M\\x07<]\\xc9\\x14\\xe1BA\\x06\\xbe\\x084'
>>> compress_un.decode('string_escape')
'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
```